# Symfony 4: how to add users to database by admin user?

Tags: symfony

I start using Symfony 4 framework. It will be a system where users should be added inside application by admin user (so without registration).
Could you suggest me how to do it, which bundle, class or which approach to use?
Also I do not want to build separate admin panel app. There will be one intranet system, where user with admin role should be able to add other users.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony is a framework that can be used to build your admin on your own or you can use the [SonataAdmin](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/index.html) Bundle which is very often used to build Admin-Panels from existing Entities.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the login functionality using the amazing Symfony MakerBundle, as documented [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html).

As Stony provided, there is the SonataAdminBundle which you can use. You can also check into [EasyAdminBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/index.html), which also generates admin tables based on your entities. EasyAdmin is somewhat a simplistic version of SonataAdmin and the configuration is quite easy to use.

Comment: Thanks, it looks that what I'm looking for is under Security topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can review your task as a simple persist of some entity (User entity) into the database. First of all you need to design your authorization\authentication strategy. I strongly recommend you to read this [security documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html)

After you create your User entity you can implement your own CRUD system or use admin bundles like [EasyAdminBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/index.html) or [SonataAdminBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/index.html). If you want to create some api application, you can also review [Api Platform](https://api-platform.com/)